# Google Docs API as Google Apps Script "Advanced Google Service"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I know I can use the Google Docs API along with the `UrlFetchApp` service. But does anyone know if the Google Docs API will be available as an "Advanced Google Service" in Google Apps Script, if so, can you tell when this will happen?

Comment: We don't work at Google. How could we tell you when they will release an unannounced product update?

Comment: Thanks for your response @tehhowch but Google is currently providing help through StackOverflow. I appreciate your dedication to reply this, but this was addressed to someone in Google.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure (I don't work at Google) but there are information channels you can monitor for news and product updates related to Google Apps Script and GSuite products:

[Google Apps Script Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/)

[What's New in GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/whatsnew/)

[GSuite Updates](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/)

Besides, "Advanced Services" are just wrappers for their respective APIs and their main purpose is to provide code completion. Under the hood, you consume the same resources as you would if you called the API directly via UrlFetch (this includes usage quotas).

If you're up to the task you can write your own implementation based on the [discovery docs](https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1) available for the Google Docs API.